# What happens if we connect a led to a monopole antenna?(on a transmitting antenna)

Tags: electricity

To my understanding, electrons flows towards a lower potential 
so if current(oscillating) flows through a monopole antenna does it mean we can connect a led anywhere on the antenna and get it to blink ?

my question is about a transmitting monopole antenna, since i find it difficult to understand how current can flow when nothing is connected at the end of the antenna.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a reasonable question from somebody trying to understand the rather counterintuitive nature of coupling to free space.

Comment: @pericynthion I ask the same question in many other posts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A diode attached to an antenna plus tuned LC circuit is the basis of the simplest possible radio: http://sci-toys.com/scitoys/scitoys/radio/homemade_radio.html

But the amount of energy available is tiny. It wouldn't be a visible glow, it would be at best something that you could just about detect with sensitive instruments.

Edit: OK, a transmitting antenna! My antenna theory is a little rusty, but I think the best way is to start by understanding a *transmission line*. Wires are not the simple objects of pure theory; between every conductor and the corresponding ground is a capacitance. We can consider the capacitance divided into little pieces for each corresponding tiny piece of wire segment. When a changing signal enters a wire, it has to fill up all the little capacitances along the way.

The antenna connected to an AC signal has a electric field wavefront travelling up it; when the wave enters it doesn't "know" that there's nothing on the end of the antenna. It reflects off the end of the antenna, and then if the antenna is designed correctly forms a *standing wave* in the antenna.

So what happens if you stick an LED in the way? I think the diode property stops this working, because it only allows current flow in one direction. You charge up the (tiny) capacitance of the antenna, and then it's full and no more current will flow at that voltage.

Comment: What's it take to make a high-efficiency LED glow? Did a subjective test that required 50 uA to see "some" light. But you need in excess of a volt to get that current to flow.

Comment: What i don't understand is why do electrons flow through the monopole antenna in the first place when only one side is connected, when the antenna is transmitting.

Comment: That changes the question somewhat. I'll edit in a response.

Comment: Electrons flow along the antenna and bunch up at one end, giving a high'ish negative voltage then they flow in the opposite direction, eventually leaving a positive charge (and voltage) as they all bunch up at the opposite end of the antenna. Etc... All this happens sinusoidally and at the frequency of the transmitter.

Comment: Ignore the electrons and focus on the electric field. The electrons don't bunch to a noticeable degree. In general thinking about electrons leads to wrong intuitions about current flow!

Comment: Do you mean that there is no flow of RF current?

Comment: There won't be a flow of AC RF current if you stick a diode in, no.

Comment: @pjc50   so basically if i take a wire and i stick it only into one side of the wall AC socket , then i get a 60Hz antenna ?

Comment: Only if it's a sufficiently long wire, such as 1/4 or 1/2 the wavelength of 60Hz. That's 2500km. https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=MLzPNpJQz9UC&pg=PA91&lpg=PA91&dq=60hz+antenna+length&source=bl&ots=iAX0BjQby6&sig=f0luBF7WGNE0BHwUaD2CoEInlqQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjKz7-M17bPAhVEcBoKHcWmA1IQ6AEIMzAD#v=onepage&q=60hz%20antenna%20length&f=false

Answer (score 1):

And where is the other end of the LED connected to? How do you avoid the LED changing the nature of your antenna? If it has a connection in the middle is it still a monopole antenna?

That said something similar to this is possible. You can use an antenna and a couple of parts to turn on an LED if the RF field is strong enough. e.g. http://www.montie.com/tag/rfid-detector/

Comment: Yes, i can understand why that would work since the em waves will cause electricity to flow through the rfid card.

Comment: but i don't understand is why do electrons flow through the monopole antenna when the antenna is transmitting.

Answer (score 1):

You can get fairly high voltages out of an antenna if you take advantage of resonance, and if the transmiter is reasonably close to the antenna.

I have done several experiments where I transmited a few mW at 13.56MHz using a square loop antenna approximately 10" on each side and then used a similar square loop to receive the signal.

Using a tuning capacitor somewhere near 100 to 150pF that resonated with the antenna inductance at 13.56MHz;  I was able to get several volts at the receiver at distances around 10ft.

But even if you can get several volts out, the amount of power received by an antenna is usually very low.  Even so, if you say you only need about 50uA * 1V = 50uW that may be possible in some cases.